# redirect to another url list of objects

Tags: spring-mvc

I've got this method in MVC controller

```
public String save(
        @RequestParam("id") Long id,
        @RequestParam(value = "book", required = false) List<Long> books,
        @RequestParam(value = "bookNow", required = false) List<Long> booksNow) {

    if (booksNow != null)
        return "redirect:/saveNow.html?id=" + id + "&bookNow=" + booksNow;
```

But the problem is that I want to redirect to another method my list of objects `booksNow` if it is not null.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveNow.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String saveNow(
        @RequestParam("id") Long id,
        @RequestParam(value = "bookNow", required = true) List<Long> booksNow) {
```

But I've got an error

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

What is the proper way to redirect list of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"&bookNow=" + booksNow` does not make sense.

booksNow will just print some java object something like List@1e23

You need to loop through the list so that your URL looks like so:

`"redirect:/saveNow.html?id=123&bookNow=234&bookNow=235&bookNow=236`